# Display headers in Excel only when the range has values

Tags: excel

[image: Layout]

I am trying to Display in Column A (A23:A29) the header of a table only when it has values on either column B (Current Pay) or C (Year to Date).

I am able to display it when both have values, or when B has a value (positive or negative). But I am not able to display the header when only C has a value (but not B). (Also could I remove #N/A when there is no values or both are zero?)

I have attached a picture to show the layout and added some dummy values to show when it works and when it doesn't.

I am using the following formula in column A:

```
=IF(COUNTA($B23:$C23)=0,"",INDEX(PP[[#Headers],[Column1]],MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B23:$C23<>0,0),0)))
```

Comment: You could just copy all the headers into that column, and then use conditional formatting to make it invisible if there is nothing in columns B or C (A simple count function would do that).  You make it invisible by changing the font color to be the same as the interior color (if `COUNT(B29:C29)=0`, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B23:$C23<>0,0),0)

gives value 2 and then it searches for header in row 2. Thats why Reference Error

If you want only headers from row number 1 then try replace above with 1 as below. Then it will take header in case both the columns are filled or any one column is filled

try this

=IF(COUNTA($B23:$C23)=0,"",INDEX(Table2[[#Headers],[Column1]],1))

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Naresh, Yes but  
=IF(COUNTA($B23:$C23)=0,"",INDEX(Table2[[#Headers],[Column1]],1))  
Shows the header regardless if column B or C has a value. I wanted only to show when it has a value on either or both of them. Otherwise, to not show any name.

Comment: Yes, Please check image added. A14 is blank, When B14 and C14 both are blank. Same formula is copied to   A8, A10, and A12

Comment: And if you want to place in column B and C and want corresponding cell in Col A blank the instead of CountA use sum as shown n the second image

Comment: Thanks @Naresh ! The sum fixed the problem I was struggling with! I appreciate the detailed answer.